# Elastic Beanstalk Returning 503 Errors

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My Elastic Beanstalk application is returning 503 server at capacity errors. I know that this happens when the application can't be reached but the application is stable everywhere else and I have tested it.

I believe that the issue is with my nginx.conf override:

```
"/opt/elasticbeanstalk/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf" :
mode: "000664"
owner: root
group: root
encoding: plain
content: |
  #WE COME FROM env.config!
    upstream nodejs {
      server 127.0.0.1:8081;
      keepalive 256;
     }
     server {
      listen 80;
        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

        location / {
          root /var/app/current/public/dist;
          proxy_set_header   Connection "";
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
          proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
          proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_comp_level 4;
        gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

     }

container_commands:
01_replace_nginx_eb_conf:
command: "mv -f        '/opt/elasticbeanstalk/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf' '/tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf'"
ignoreErrors: false
```

I'd like to be able to serve my 'dist' folder of the app which contains a React web application through EBS.

I'm not very familiar with DevOps or nginx. Are there any glaring issues here that would cause my app to always be 503?

Comment: Have you checked the logs?

Comment: Yeah, nothing in them indicating a failure app seems to be running fine. nginx logs just have warns nothing that should crash the whole app

Comment: Umm... Might need to go a different direction then. Or share the logs in case you are missing something. As far as a different direction, if you do not need any backend services on the ec2 instance then try out S3 static hosting or Github Pages. Both work great for front end frameworks.